# Add multiple criteria to array formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

I'm having a hard time finding a way to add a second criterion to my array formula.

I have 3 columns that I'm tracking data from and I'm outputting this data onto a separate 'summary' tab.

Tab 1 has the following columns

B (quantity), C (employee name), and D (date)

Tab 2 has the following cells

A3 (daily total), B3 (weekly total), C3 (monthly total)
A7 (daily total for employee mark), A7 (weekly total for employee mark), C7 (monthly total for employee mark)

I created an array formula so that I could count all of the quantities added up over certain date ranges (daily, weekly, and monthly), but I also want to output this data and separate it by the employee also.

I can't for the life of me figure out a way to add this to my current formula or find another way to do it where it accurately can track the daily, weekly, and monthly sums of the quantity column.

I've attached a demo sheet so that you can see what I'm working with.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iAS_U33lPCr-8xnmfK9WuL5URnK8ovY7V-TlKrrSKdQ/edit?usp=sharing

I really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(Updating!B:B, 
 WEEKNUM(Updating!D:D), 47,
   MONTH(Updating!D:D), 11,
    YEAR(Updating!D:D), 2019,
         Updating!C:C, "Santosh"))
```

[image: 0]

---

and for Rina:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(Updating!B:B, 
 WEEKNUM(Updating!D:D), 47,
   MONTH(Updating!D:D), 11,
    YEAR(Updating!D:D), 2019,
         Updating!C:C, "Rina"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks. That is working for the weekly and monthly. I think the daily one is still not working though. I tried to make it automatically add the current days date in the date column on sheet 2, and then I want the summary page for daily to add up the quantity for the current days total.

Comment: for daily use: `=COUNTIFS(Updating!B:B, TODAY(), Updating!C:C, "Rina")`